# Differential equation $yy'+2y=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation: $ yy'+2y=3x$. I tried a couple of substitutions (for example the obvious one $z=y^2$) and variation of constants on it but without success. Do You know some trick to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint:** Try $ y = v x$, so $y'  = v + v' x$. Substitute those two and continue. It looks like this will lead to a Separable Equation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!